# Python not working in Azure pipeline build VM

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

Im trying to run a python script in an Azure pipeline, but it doesnt seem to be working. It keeps telling me `'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I have installed python and added it to the path, when I type `python` in the command line on the VM it works:
[image]

But when I try to run the following command line task in the pipeline, it fails:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: 'python ./tools/setPythonClientVersion.py $(Build.BuildNumber)'
  displayName: Set Client Version
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar issues and solved it by adding the python interpreter argument to the yaml. Something like this:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: Set Client Version
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
     # add your script here
    pythonInterpreter: 'c:/python/python.exe'
```

Comment: were you using the CmdLine@2 task or were you using a different task? When I add the argument i get the following error message: `Unexpected value 'pythonInterpreter'
`

Comment: You are correct, it was a different task, I'll add the code above and see if it helps resolve your problem. Apologises, I misremembered.